# How to use Pipe in replace HTML markup?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How can use Pipe in replace function with HTML markup in Angular?

Angular HTML:

```
<ion-list class="item-autocom" *ngFor="let word of words">
    {{ word | replace }}
</ion-list>
```

Angular TS Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    return value.replace('h', 'gi', '<b>$&</b>');

  }
}
```

This is the output:

> `<b>$&</b>`allo

But I need:

> **h**allo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
{{ word | replace }}
```

with

```
<i [outerHTML]="word | replace"></i>
```

so your text will be parsed as html.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped.